# How can I show a list of all tasks without incomplete predecessors in Microsoft Project?

Tags: ms-project

I would like to see a list of all tasks that satisfy one of the following:

- The task has no predecessors
- Every predecessor that the task has is marked as 100% complete.

I can add simple filters from **View > Filter > New Filter**, but I can't figure out how to test every predecessor of a task.  Is there a way to use some advanced filtering functionality to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Use VBA to populate a custom flag field matching your conditions. Something like this should get you close:

```
Sub ShouldStart()
Dim t As Task
Dim tp As Task

For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If Not t Is Nothing Then
        t.Flag5 = False
        If t.PercentComplete < 100 Then
            If t.PredecessorTasks.Count = 0 Then
                t.Flag5 = True
                GoTo NextTask
            Else
                For Each tp In t.PredecessorTasks
                    If tp.PercentComplete < 100 Then GoTo NextTask
                Next tp
                t.Flag5 = True
            End If
        End If

    End If
NextTask:
Next t

End Sub
```

Step 2: Make a filter based on the custom flag field.